# Vuejs Warning expected boolean found string

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to Vuejs, i just install vue-flip plugin at Nuxtjs and write this tag:
This is the tag at index.vue:

```
<vue-flip active-hover="TRUE" class="flip">
```

and at the console i see this warning :

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "activeHover". Expected Boolean, got String with value "TRUE"
```

I try to change from true to 1, but the keeps still remains

The message point to this location
At:

```
---> <Flip> at src/Flip.vue
       <Pages/index.vue> at pages/index.vue
         <Nuxt>
           <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
             <Root>
```

How can i get rid of this message ?

Comment: Simply add `active-hover` as attribute?

Comment: how is it done ? declaring at props ?

Comment: Replace the "TRUE" with "true"?

Comment: i try, remains the message : [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "activeHover". Expected Boolean, got String with value "true".

Comment: This is the plugin : https://vue-flip.kevingrandemange.net/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Instead of

```
<vue-flip active-hover="TRUE" class="flip">
```

you should use

```
<vue-flip v-bind:active-hover="true" class="flip">
```

or shorter

```
<vue-flip :active-hover="true" class="flip">
```

Comment: would be nice an explanation about why should use the v-bind directive

Comment: @EttoreP without v:bind the value inside the quotes is always a string. With v-bind the string is parsed as javascript expression.

Comment: This is something I've always wondered: is `v-bind` slow?  Or at least slower than not binding?  For example, if I say `v-bind:bool="false"`, does that have to run another javascript thread to parse `'false'` as `false`?

Answer (score 6):

The default when providing a prop with no value is *true*

Change this

```
<vue-flip active-hover="TRUE" class="flip">
```

to

```
<vue-flip active-hover class="flip">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue; I was passing a boolean prop to a child component from a vuex store. My issue was my getter was actually a string & in my component I was validating that it was a boolean.

Error:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "userIsAuthenticated". Expected Boolean, got String with value "true"

Here is how I resolved my issue.

```
// ParentComponent.vue 

...

computed: {
    userIsAuthenticated() {
        return this.$store.getters["user/authenticated"];  // String
        return this.$store.getters["user/authenticated"] === "true";  // Boolean
    },
}
```

```
// ChildComponent.vue

...

props: {
    userIsAuthenticated: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: () => false,
    },
}
```

To expand a bit more, in my vuex store I could also have done this:

```
export const state = {
    authenticated: (localStorage.getItem("authenticated")) ?localStorage.getItem("authenticated") === "true" : false,
}
```